# Find out common elements in array in java and android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

Hi In my code I am having following arrays:-

String[] Category = {Rental, Gifts, Gifts};

float[] Amount = {14.76, 15.0, 20.0};

My problem is I want find out same element from first array as there is "Gifts". And according to that convert second one.
So the output will be as:-

Category = {Rental,Gifts};

Amount = {14.76, 35.0};

Will anybody tell me how to achieve this in java?

Comment: try using equalIgnoreCase method in String

Comment: @Hugo Sousa : Hi I am not getting any logic, can't understand from where to start?

Comment: Are you allowed to use HashMap or ArrayLists instead of arrays? Or is this for some kind of assignment? HashMap would be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Map` here: Category value should be mapped to Amount value (I would name them in lowercase according to Java coding style):

```
Map<String, Float> costs = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < category.length; ++i) {
    Float initial = costs.get(category[i]);
    if (initial == null)
        initial = 0f;
    costs.put(category[i], initial + amount[i]);
}
```

After these actions, `costs` map would contain something like `(Rental -> 14.76, Gifts -> 35.0)`

To get the arrays back (not sure, why it can be useful), you should just iterate through `Map`'s items and write them into an array:

```
category = new String[costs.size()];
amount = new Float[costs.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry: costs.entrySet()) {
    category[i] = entry.getKey();
    amount[i] = entry.getValue();
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Hi                                                                       how I am going to separate those? because I need Rental,Gifts in single array and 14.76,35.0 in another array.

Comment: @user3702484 take a look at the fixed code.